# Better ways to simulate poor network connection on iOS devices

Tags: ios, macos, testing, networking, connectivity

Task: to simulate a poor network connection on iOS devices with possibility of changing simulation settings programmatically based on a particular schedule.

This is what I came up with so far:

Solution #1: mac computer, which is turned into a WiFi hotspot, with enabled Network Link Conditioner. iOS devices connect to this hot spot.

Pros:

- managing Network Link Conditioner tool running on mac is easier, especially when you have 20-30 iOS devices under the test.
- it is not critical for test if you have very limited number of iOS devices.

Cons:

- No obvious ways to automate scheduling different settings in Network Link Conditioner.

As an alternative to Network Link Conditioner, some people mentioned to play around with [ipfw rules](http://furbo.org/2009/03/24/slow-ride-make-it-easy/). Even though ipfw was removed from 10.10, it is still an option for previous versions of OS X.

=====

Solution #2: multiple iOS devices with their instances of Network Link Conditioner with different settings.

Pros:

- no need to use a dedicated mac computer as a WiFi hotspot.

Cons:

- No obvious ways to programmatically manipulate Network Conditioner Settings in iOS.
- very tedious procedure of changing Network Link Conditioner settings on each iOS device.

=====

Any other suggestions? Like making a WiFi hotspot on windows platform?